# How to get the contents under a particular column in a table from Wikipedia using soup & python

Tags: python, html, excel, parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to get the href links that the contents point to under a particular column from a table in wikipedia. The page is "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_2015". On this page there are a few tables with class "wikitable". I need the links of the contents under the column **Title** for each row that they point to. I would like them to be copied onto an excel sheet.

I do not know the exact code of searching under a particular column but I came upto this far and I am getting a ***"Nonetype object is not callable"***. I am using bs4. I wanted to extract atleast somepart of the table so I could figure out narrowing to the href links under the Title column I want but I am ending up with this error. The code is as below:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_2015').read())
for row in soup('table', {'class': 'wikitable'})[1].tbody('tr'):
    tds = row('td')
    print (tds[0].string, tds[0].string)
```

A little guidance appreciated. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out that the none type error might be related to the table filtering. Corrected code is as below:

```
import urllib2

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer


content = urllib2.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Telugu_films_of_2015").read()  
filter_tag = SoupStrainer("table", {"class":"wikitable"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, parse_only=filter_tag)

links=[] 
for sp in soup.find_all(align="center"):
    a_tag = sp('a')
    if a_tag:
        links.append(a_tag[0].get('href'))
```